# How to fix a Method 'Location' of object '_AppointmentItem' failed error?

Tags: vba, outlook

I read various elements of an open appointment item and display it in a message box:

```
Private Sub MessageAppointmentInfo()    

    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim mySubject As String
    Dim myLocation As String
    Dim myStartDate As Date

    Set objApp = Application

    Set objItem = objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)

    With objItem

        mySubject = .Subject
        myLocation = .Location
        myStartDate = .Start

    End With

    MsgBox mySubject & myStartDate & myLocation

End Sub
```

If I comment out myLocation and myStartDate, it runs.

Why won't the location and the start date work the same as the subject?

I get:

> Method 'Location' of object '_AppointmentItem' failed

When I hit debug, it highlights `myLocation = .Location`.

I'm not familiar with Outlook VBA--I'm much more comfortable with Access and Excel.

Comment: Are you sure you have selected an `AppointmentItem`?  A MailItem, for example, has a `Subject` but not a `Location` or a `Start`.  If you had selected a `MailItem`, these are the errors you would expect.

Comment: I definitely have an AppointmentItem selected, according to the locals window and based on the subject that I get when I've commented out location (it is the subject of the appointment that I'm trying to work with). In the Locals window I noticed that it says     : Location : <The operation failed.> : String and    : Start : <The operation failed.> : Date

Comment: An AppoitnmentItem has a property MeetingStatus.  Values for MeetingStatus include olMeetingCanceled = 5 = "The scheduled meeting has been cancelled".  Could the selected AppointmentItem have a MeetingStatus for which Location and Start are meaningless?

Comment: Like you I started with Excel.  I found the Outlook Object model confusing and poorly documented.  I did buy a highly recommended book but I was not impressed.  I learnt (and am still learning) through experimentation.  Can you access some of the other properties?

Comment: The other properties that I can access are the ones that don't show "The operation failed" under value in the Locals window. So, for example, I can show the CreationTime with no problem at all. I can show the EntryID and Organizer. Why would some operations fail and others not? I do have a Location for the appointment. MeetingStatus property has "the operation failed" for the value in the locals window.

Comment: I am a home user and have no `AppointmentItem`s to experiment with. My reading around this type of issue suggests the code that creates an Outlook object need not initialise every property of the object and Outlook does not provide default values.  You could try using an `On Error` block around the access to these properties. Perhaps one of `IsNull`, `IsEmpty`, `IsMissing` or `IsError` will return a useful value.

Answer (score 0):

If you mainly want to avoid the error where the Location is not available anyway, let the execution simply continue with next instruction in case of failure and supply blank Location instead:

```vb
...

With objItem

    mySubject = .Subject
    myLocation = ""
    On Error Resume Next
    myLocation = .Location
    On Error Goto 0 ' switch off error handling
    myStartDate = .Start

End With

...
```